# Notifynder 3.1 on Laravel no result

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have installed Notifynder 3.1 inside my laravel app, for try if it works I have just insert one notification :

```
 $from_user_id = 1;
 $to_user_id = 2;
 Notifynder::category('hello')
        ->from($from_user_id)
        ->to($to_user_id)
        ->url('http://www.yourwebsite.com/page')
        ->send();
```

It works properly, if I check inside database notification is there.

The problem happens when I try to get the notification in that way:

```
$user = User::find(2);
dd($user->getNotifications($limit = 10, $paginate = 1, $order = 'desc'));
```

The result is that:
[Notification result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB66I.png)

The result is empty, but in database notification exist

[Notification Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswvq.png)

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm have this in your `app/User.php`:

```
use Fenos\Notifynder\Notifable;

class User extends Model
{

   use Notifable;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem, and i solve it. 
if you changed the users primary key, then in vendor\fenos\notifynder\src\Notifynder\Notifable.php
change this `$this->id` to this `$this->getKey()`.